# How do you separate bones and name them?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I am working on a tutorial about low-poly modeling, but I am having difficulty in separating the bones and naming them individually. How do I do that?

Here is the tutorial I am currently working on, particularly the part I am having difficulty with...

https://youtu.be/XkiWBSSuxLw?t=172

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways that work.  Here's one that always works:

- Select the armature
- Enter *Edit Mode* or *Pose Mode*
- Select an individual bone by left clicking on it.
- Go to the Properties panel to the *Bone* properties tab and click the bone name.
  [image: current name selected]
- Type in the new name.

The one he's using in the video:

- Select the armature
- Enter *Edit Mode* or *Pose Mode*
- Select an individual bone by left clicking on it.
- Type <kbd>F2</kbd> (The key labeled F2 on the function row of your keyboard)[image: changing the name with F2]
- Type in the new name.

Comment: When I do press F2, it does nothing but darken the screen (I don't have a feature for that Blender feature).

Comment: sounds like you have a keyboard where the function keys are mapped to OS functionality.  There's usually some shift-like key for enabling and disabling that but it varies by keyboard.  Anyway, the first approach always works, no matter the OS or keyboard.